# onbeforeunload not called on a JS redirect

Tags: javascript, error-handling, requirejs, dom-events, onbeforeunload

### Site Setup

- using [**requireJS**](http://requirejs.org/), we're loading a bunch of modules on a page
- we have a **global error handler** ([*window.onError*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror)) which will send any JS errors to our tracking server
- we have an `onbeforeunload` handler set up, so when the visitor is *leaving a page*, we set a global variable `window.exitting = true` to say that any more JS errors should be disregarded, and therefore not reported to us

Here are the relevant code sections:

```
if (typeof window.onbeforeunload != 'undefined') {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {window.exitting = true;}, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onbeforeunload', function() {window.exitting = true;});
  }
}

window.onerror = function() {
  // do not log false errors when navigating away
  if (window.exitting) return true;

  // ... code that sends this error to us follows here
};
```

---

### The Problem

On some pages, we use [Visual Website Optimizer](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/) for A/B testing that **redirects** the page to a different URL on load. This is most probably causing all scripts being loaded to stop, firing up *requireJS's own onError function*. This function will then throw a JS error that *should be now disregarded by our global error handling function* above. **But it isn't.**

What happens instead is that we get a lot of false positives logged into our tracking server which does not break the page for visitors at all.

It seems that the `onbeforeunload` function is not setting the global variable at all, so our global error handler still logs all those unimportant errors into our server.

Any thoughts on this? We've run out of ideas now.

Comment: Are you sure that the `addEventListener` call is even executed before the other code is navigating away from the page?

Comment: @nmaier we tried `window.onbeforeunload = function() { window.exitting = true; };` before with same results and only converted to the standards-following `addEventListener` afterwards - and they both were tried in page head as well as first scripts to load